# How to add function in fragment

Tags: android, fragment

EDIT:

I'm new in android and i try to use fragments in my app. I try to use a fragment function in my activity but i got a null pointer exception..

Fragment:

```
public class  VideoviewFragment extends Fragment {

private View card;

public static VideoviewFragment create() {
    return new VideoviewFragment();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_videoview, container, false);
    card = (View) view.findViewById(R.id.card_video);
    return view;
}

public void setalphacard(float value){
    card.setAlpha(value);
}

}
```

In main activity i want to do that for example (i simplified my code):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // Viewpager
    final SmartFragmentStatePagerAdapter adapterViewPager;
    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.am_view_pager);
    adapterViewPager = new MainPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);

    final VideoviewFragment videoviewFragment = (VideoviewFragment) adapterViewPager.getRegisteredFragment(2);
    videoviewFragment.setalphacard(0.3f);

}
}
```

Main pager adapter:

```
public class MainPagerAdapter extends SmartFragmentStatePagerAdapter {


public MainPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

     switch (position){

         case 0:
             return CameraFragment.create();
         case 1:
             return OptionFragment.create();
         case 2:
             return VideoviewFragment.create();
     }

     return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}
}
```

Comment: you have to declare Object(card) of view globally in fragment

Answer (score 1):

You just have to declare the `View` globally like this:

```
public class  VideoviewFragment extends Fragment {

private View card;

public static VideoviewFragment create() {
    return new VideoviewFragment();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_videoview, container, false);
   card = (View) view.findViewById(R.id.card_video);
    return view;
}

public void setalphacard(float value){
    card.setAlpha(value);
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks but i tried this, and i got a null pointer excpetion in main activity when i try to use that function..

Answer (score 0):

Declare your View Object globally in your fragment.